# Bluemix DevOps pipeline ruby app unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery, ibm-cloud-tools

Im currently stuck in trying to run ruby on rails unit tests on the delivery pipeline on bluemix.

From what I have researched, the bluemix pipeline test function runs on ubuntu 14.04, and when trying to install ruby and rails, i keep getting blocked and cannot proceed with the build as I don't have access to the sudo password.

Has anyone been successful in implementing ruby on rails unit tests on the bluemix pipeline.

Any advise appreciated.

Thanks

Dale

Answer (score 1):

The Bluemix DevOps pipeline allows limited use of sudo which includes allowing you to run `sudo apt-get` and `sudo apt-key` commands.  Hopefully these will be enough to get your ruby on rails unit tests working.

If not, please post more information on where/how you are failing.